# dotenv not working when deploy React code to S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, aws-codebuild, dotenv

I have a `.env` file with one variable `API_BASE_URL`. And I use `webpack`, `dotenv` and `webpack.DefinePlugin` to build the react app. The code is working on my localhost and my local server by `serve dist` using `http-server`. When I deploy my to S3 using AWS codepipeline, even though I set `API_BASE_URL` on AWS codebuild part, but the deployed app on S3 cannot load the variable. Anyone knows where is wrong?

webpack:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
module.exports = () => {
    const env = {} || dotenv.config().parsed
    const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
        prev[`${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next])
        return prev
    }, {})
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
    ]
...
```

.env(it's on the root directory)

```
API_BASE_URL = xxxxxx
```

App file

```
const App = () => {
    console.log("API_BASE_URL", API_BASE_URL)
    return (
...
```

set enviroment variable on aws
[image]

cannot find the varible on S3

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using cra, you need to add `REACT_APP_` prefix before your env variable name.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

But in any case to access the environment variable you have to call it from `process.env` -> `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME`

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env